# Postgres how to grant references on a table

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I'm using a multitenant system on Laravel, and my tenant need to access a table on a main database, how can I grant an access to him?

In MySQL I know that I can do it using:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON maindb.cities TO "f8780082-f69f-424a-92bb-2b70a9520b98" IDENTIFIED BY '0b82eb3089061cc99fadd7b6ff88de6b
```

But using postgres, how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the `identified` by. and make sure that `"f8780082-f69f-424a-92bb-2b70a9520b98"` is indeed a role (user). But `references` grants the privilege to create a foreign key referencing that table. It does not grant "access" to that table. For that you need to use the `select` privilege

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure, i'd like a foreign key in that database, if I remove IDENTIFIED "works" but postgres recognize maindb like a schema, and not a database!

How can i fix it? Thanks

Comment: You can't define foreign keys across databases. Use schemas instead. What MySQL calls a "database" is actually a schema, so a schema in Postgres is the natural match for that.

Comment: hmmmm bad news :( Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: What's wrong with using schemas?

Comment: My system works with different database, I will try to change to schemas! Thx

Comment: For all intents and purposes MySQL's "databases" are the same as schemas in Postgres. If you migrate from one system to another you can not blindly assume that things work the same.

Comment: You are right... I will do this... Thanks again @a_horse_with_no_name